# Calculating volume change of sphere with differential

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following function:

$$
u(r)= \frac{4}{3} \pi  r^{3}
$$

I need to calculate the % change of volume of the sphere using differential if I increase the radius by 1% (0.01).

Can anyone help me here, I'm clueless how to solve this.

Comment: Given the suggested approach, the obvious first steps are to try and answer the questions "what is the differential?" and "How does the differential measure change?"

Comment: With help of differential i need to calculate by how much % does the volume of the shpere change if I increase the radius by 1%.

Answer (score 1):

Consider some function $f(x)$. Let's say you know $f(x)$ and you want to evaluate $f(x+\Delta x)$. For small changes in $x$, we can approximate the $\Delta f$
as follows:

$\Delta f=f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\approx f^{\prime}(x)\Delta x=df$

$df$ is the differential. For your case, your function is the volume and you are changing the radius($r$) by a small amount.
So understand and use the above definition to do your calculation.

Comment: Thanks, means a lot but it dosent help me i couldnt atend the class when they were doing this so now im clules.

Comment: This was asked by @miha, but Kellax seems more concerned about it? Something seems fishy.

Comment: @kellax: then please flag it and ask a moderator to combine the accounts.  Helps you with reputation, helps the rest of us with lack of confusion.

Comment: @kellax here is a link to a tutorial on differentials. Do the examples. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Differentials.aspx. This should help. How much of single variable calculus do you know? Ask more if things are not clear. Be specific with what you don't understand.